# Error 500 when I'm trying to filter (sorting, paging etc.) my grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm having trouble with getting the sorting and paging function to work with my grid. I have a Grid that is filled with data, with Ajax Databindning. I however, receive an Error 500 when I'm trying to refresh or change the filtering information. I have a search function which passes every input to the controller.

```
        public ActionResult Results(FormCollection form)
    {
        string foo= form["foo"];
        string bar= form["bar"];


        model.Result(foo, bar);
        var data = model.FilterResult().Select(o => new SearchViewModel
                        {
                            //Binding SearchViewModel propertys with the XML-elements found in model.FilterResults().
                            Foo= o.Element("Foo").Value,
                            Bar = o.Element("Bar").Value
                        });

        return View(data);
    }
```

In the controller I call a "Result()-Method", which basically sets the input values to Properties in my Model. The "FilterResult()"-method uses the user input (properties) for querying XML-files using LINQ. That method returns a IENumerable with XElements.

My view looks like this:

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
                .Name("Search")
                .PrefixUrlParameters(false)
                .DataKeys(keys => { keys.Add(m => m.Foo); })
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(o => o.Foo);
                                columns.Bound(o => o.Bar);
                            })
                .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                {
                    dataBinding.Ajax()       
                        .Select("Results", "Search").Enabled(true);   
                })
                .Pageable(pager => pager.Enabled(true).PageSize(20))
                .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true).OrderBy(sortOrder => sortOrder.Add(o => o.TimeStamp).Ascending()))
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable.Enabled(true))
                .Render();
```

I receive both a Error 500 and a NullException for the input values (in my controller) when I try to change any filtering setting. I've realized that it's null since it's calls back to the controller without the user have made a new search, resulting in null values. So I'm wondering how this can be done? I only want to do the filtering and sorting on the data that's already in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If foo and bar are form elements on your page, you could submit the page using ajax, so that when you databind, you are calling the data the same way. Then in your view, add ClientEvents to the grid.

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
```

The onDataBinding function would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onDataBinding(e) {
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo').value;
    var bar = document.getElementById('bar').value;
    var params = { pFoo: foo, pBar: bar };
    var paramsStr = $.param(params);
    var selectUrl = '@Url.Action("Results", "Search")'
      + "?" + paramsStr;
    var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
    grid.ajax.selectUrl = selectUrl;
  } 
</script>
```

In your contoller, the parameters you pass in would be foo and bar.

```
public ActionResult Results(string pFoo, string pBar)
```

The submit function would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function displaySummary() {
    var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
    var foo = document.getElementById('foo').value;
    var bar = document.getElementById('bar').value;
    $.ajax(
    {
      type: 'POST',
      url: '@Url.Action("Results", "Search")',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { pFoo: foo, pBar: bar },
      success: function (result) {
        grid.dataBind(result);
      },
      error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert("Sorry! Error. " + status + error);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Okay I will try that. I tried something similar though I didn't submit the page with Ajax, only calling it. That didn't work though :)

Comment: Im not able to get the form values into the controller. It seems like the displaySummary() function is not run. I put that function in my view where the form is and the onDataBinding in the grid-view. I've also tried to use $(#'Foo').val() without result.

Comment: First make sure whether displaySummary is being called. Put an alert at the start of the function: function displaySummary() { alert('in displaySummary'); If that works, then check the foo and bar values the same way.

Comment: I managed to solve it using the displaySummary function when the form is submitted. 
I then returned the view containing the result. In my grid I had it data binding to a new controller, which binds the values received from the other controller. That controller returns a new GridModel. Thanks for the input! :)